# Ruby Regex Web Parsing

Tags: ruby, regex, url

I am working on a simple Ruby script to parse the names of race horses from a webpage.  This Regex works on http://rubular.com/, but my script does not print anything when I run it.

```
require 'open-uri';

url = "http://www.bloodhorse.com/horse-racing/race/race-results";
connection = open(url);
content = connection.read;

if(content =~ /(<span class="horseName">)(\n)(.*?)(\>)(.*?)(<\/a>)/)
    print $5,"\n";
end
```

An example of some of the page's source is:

```
<li value="2">
<span class="horseName">
<a href="/horse-racing/thoroughbred/felonious-fred/2010">Felonious Fred</a>
```

So I would think that my script should return the 5th capture of the matching Regex, which in this case should be "Felonious Fred". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If I were you, I would use something like Nokogiri.

Comment: I feel it necessary to link this immortal answer from the Java section of SO : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0):

If you are scrapping a webpage, I suggest you use Nokogiri gem.  Will save you the trouble of Regex.